# Xcode 11, Swift 5, iOS Stack View Problem/Challenge

Tags: ios, layout, view, swift5, stacked

I am working on a requirement in iOS, using Xcode 11 and Swift 5. A view comprised of 6 boxes, 5 boxes of equal size (width & height) and the sixth is the equivalent in size to 4 of the smaller boxes. See image of the required layout.

[[image: Interface Builder View of box layout]]

each of the boxes will need to contain an Image with a line of text underneath. I have only shown 3 boxes with images but all 9 will need the image and text.

I have tried numerous combinations of views, stack views and nested stack views. I have the following structure which seems to layout ok, but i keep getting hung up on various constraint errors and when running the code on simulator or on real device the layout is completely screwed up.

The main problem seems to be the one box (box 6) which is twice the width and height of the other boxes. One way i have worked this is to create a 9box stacked view - 3 boxes stacked vertically within a Horizontal stack view with the 3 rows of horizontally stacked box views. I then find the x & y co-ords of the 4 boxes for a view to be created programatically to overlay the stacked views. This seems to work but its not very elegant and I'd rather use a pure stacked view solution if one exists. The following images show the current structure.

[structure view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GElVJ.png)

[structure view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjIs.png)

Comment: Could you commit your code on Github? We'll pull source code to review

Comment: Hi, ive got the stacked view as a test project, this is on github now https://github.com/appydays/UIStackViewTest. Thank you!

Comment: Please check my github. I have created a new viewcontroller with stackview like you want. [https://github.com/hhoangna/teststackview](https://github.com/hhoangna/teststackview)

Comment: And why you use stack view? For this UI, you can use 6 UIView. Easier to constraint!

Comment: Hi! thank you!!. I opted for stack view as i felt they may have been easier to layout and more responsive ... im farily new to this though so its a bit of a learning curve ;) I'll check out the controller. Thanks again.

Comment: The viewcontroller works perfect for me, thank you again!